# Saving in django forms using FormView

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm creating a form that will change the state of reserve book, I have this

```
    class LibraryReserveForm(CrispyFormMixin, forms.Form):

          def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
              self.manager = kwargs.pop('manager')
              super(LibraryReserveForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

          def save(self):
              self.instance.reserve_status = 'approved'

              self.instance.save()

              return self.manager
```

models.py

```
    class ReservedBooks(TimeStampedModel):

        BOOK_RESERVE_STATUS = Choices(
             ('for_approval', "For Approval"),
             ('approve', "Approved"),
             ('cancelled', "Cancelled"),
             ('rejected', "Rejected")
        )

        reserve_status = models.CharField(
               _('Status'),
               max_length=32,
               choices=BOOK_RESERVE_STATUS,
               default='for_approval'
        )

    ...
```

view

```
    class LibraryReserveView(
          ProfileTypeRequiredMixin,
          MultiplePermissionsRequiredMixin,
          FormView,
    ):

    model = ReservedBooks
    template_name = 'library/reserved_list.html'
    form_class = LibraryReserveForm

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(LibraryReserveView, self).get_form_kwargs()

        kwargs.update({
            'manager': self.request.user.manager,
        })

        return kwargs
```

urls

```
    url(
        r'^reserve/(?P<pk>\d+)/$',
        views.LibraryReserveView.as_view(),
        name='reserved'
    ),
```

everytime I submit the button I print something in the save() method of the forms but its not printing something therefore that method is not called. How do you called the save method ? Thanks

Comment: Why not use an `UpdateView`? This is a `FormView` that will update the instance with as primary key the `pk` in the url pattern.

Comment: Shouldn't you by the way use a `ModelForm`? A `Form` has no `instance`.

Comment: Your `LibraryReserveForm` has no fields so it doesn't do anything.

Comment: I saw some code  that did the use `forms.Forms` with saving and it works. However, mine is not. I will recode this one to use UpdateView. Thank you

Comment: Hello I try also the modelForm however the save method also dont call when I click.

Comment: @dengm: what exactly are you doing with the `manager` object here?

Comment: Actually, I will use that 'manager' when I change the book status so I will know whose user changed the status. The problem is I can't call the save method to even change it.

Answer (score 0):

A `FormView` does not handle saving the object. It simply calls `form_valid` that will redirect to the `success_url`. But an `UpdateView` adds boilerplate code to pass the instance to the form, and will save the form.

You work with a `Form`, but a `Form` has no `.instance` attribute. A `ModelForm` has, so it might be better to use a `ModelForm` here:

```
class LibraryReserveForm(CrispyFormMixin, forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.manager = kwargs.pop('manager')
        super(LibraryReserveForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.instance.reserve_status = 'approved'
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Then we can make use of an `UpdateView`:

```
from django.views.generic import UpdateView

class LibraryReserveView(
          ProfileTypeRequiredMixin,
          MultiplePermissionsRequiredMixin,
          UpdateView
    ):

    model = ReservedBooks
    template_name = 'library/reserved_list.html'
    form_class = LibraryReserveForm
    success_url = …

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(LibraryReserveView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs.update(
            manager=self.request.user.manager
        )
        return kwargs
```

You still need to specify the `sucess_url` here: the URL to which a successful POST request will redirect to implement the [*Post/Redirect/Get* pattern [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).